# Using Powershell to auto fill part of a computer name in a rename script?

Tags: powershell, rename

There are a few questions on this, with answers, but unfortunately i cant get them to work with my situation. I am newer to powershell so thats probably why.

Doing deployments for a hospital and each computer has a specific department it goes to. Each computer is named in a scheme with a max of 12 characters. For example: WPET04MRIT45 is an old device. So we swap it out with a new machine that needs renamed to WPET04MRIT65.

Now ive setup a script that does it just fine. But would i be able to have it print out the first 10 characters for me so then all i have to do is enter the new number and be on my way?

Right now, this is the script i have:

```
$newname = Read-Host -Prompt 'Computers new name'

$user = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the username'

Rename-Computer -ComputerName localhost -NewName $newname -DomainCredential $user; Restart-Computer'
```

So when i run it, it outputs "Computers new name" *i type the full new name*

then it asks for my username *i put in my username*

then i hit enter and it prompts me for my password and restarts.

Which is fine, it works. its way faster this way than the old way. But with that said:

Could i have it pull the first 10 digits of the computer name from "localhost" and have it output it in the "Computers new name" field when it comes up, so that i only have to enter in the last 2 characters?

So for example, the output would be:

Computers new name: **first 10 characters from localhost** *I'd fill in the last 2 characters*

Username: *I put in my username*

and then it prompts for password and restarts.

Comment: You could try `$NewName = $(-join $env:computername[0..9]) + (read-host "Enter the last two characters of the new name: )`.

Comment: Note that the read-host provides it's own semicolon regardless if the prompt is specified or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want it to print out the first 10 characters and only have to type 2, you could do a `Write-Host` followed by the `Read-Host`

```
Write-Host "    Current name: $($env:COMPUTERNAME)`n`n"

$lasttwo = Read-Host -Prompt '    Enter the last two characters of the new name'

$newname = $env:computername[0..9] + $lasttwo

$user = Read-Host -Prompt '    Input the username'

Rename-Computer -ComputerName localhost -NewName $newname -DomainCredential $user; Restart-Computer
```

**Edit**

Thanks to AdminOfThings for pointing out if the name is less than 10 characters the above approach would error. The following changes would prevent errors *unless [strictmode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-5.1) version 3.0 is set*

```
Write-Host "    Current name: $($env:COMPUTERNAME)`n`n"

$lasttwo = Read-Host -Prompt '    Enter the last two characters of the new name'

$newname = $($env:COMPUTERNAME).Substring(0,10) + $lasttwo

$user = Read-Host -Prompt '    Input the username'

Rename-Computer -ComputerName localhost -NewName $newname -DomainCredential $user; Restart-Computer
```

Comment: Another thing to consider even though the OP has not mentioned this condition is that the computer name could be less than 10 characters already. In that case, the substring approach will error on the length without additional calculations.

Comment: Ahh yes he did say "max of 12" - definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: That wont be an issue as, and i should have made it more clear, each computer name is 12 characters regardless, so that substring will not affect anything. I appreciate the responses.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Mind if I add your approach to this answer? It will not error if it's less.

Comment: @DougMaurer, go for it. Even my approach in the comments isn't immune. If strict mode version 3 is set, mine will fail on shorter length systems. So there are caveats to  the *simple* solutions.